# Разница между & и && при работе в Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Допустим есть задача найти максимальное время звонков среди мужчин не пользующихся неким тарифным планом (вся информация хранится в DataFrame).
Обратившись к нужным столбцам, получаем решение

```
df[(df['Gender'] == 'Man') & (df['Tariff plan'] == 'No')]['Total intl minutes'].max()
```

Почему в условиях стоит знак `&`, а не `&&` или `and`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что это **"побитовое и"** `&`, а не "логическое и" `and` (в других языках, например `C#`, "логическое и" это `&&`).

```
(df['Gender'] == 'Man') & (df['Tariff plan'] == 'No')
```

В этом выражении и слева и справа участвуют **вектора**, между которыми производится "побитовая" операция, то есть делается "логическое и" между соответствующими элементами двух (или более) векторов, вернее между булевыми элементами объектов типа `Pandas.Series`. И на выходе у этой операции получается не просто одиночное значение `True` или `False`, как у оператора `and`, а **вектор** `Pandas.Series` из булевых значений.

На аглийской части Stackoverflow можно найти [более подробное объяснение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46350913/8324991), но суть там та же.

P.S. Можно задаться вопросом: а почему в случае оператора `==` не сделали отдельные "побитовую" и "логическую" версию, но тут я так сходу не смогу подсказать. Но, вероятно, именно этот факт вас несколько и озадачил в данном случае - почему тут так, а тут эдак. Ведь тут тоже производится именно поэлементное сравнение, результатом которого является вектор:

```
df['Gender'] == 'Man'
```

Comment: Непонятно конкретно специфика использования побитовой операции, а не условной(т.е  and)

Comment: @ego_xxx Я добавил ссылку на подробное описание на английском. Но наверное проще запомнить. Вся суть в том, что `and` применяется к объектам в целом. А тут надо нужен поэлементный оператор.

Answer (score 5):

Потому, что оператора `&&` в python нет, а выражение

```
x and y
```

приблизительно соответствует выражению

```
y if bool(x) else x
```

Это поведение зашито на уровне синтаксиса, переопределению не подлежит, и явно не соответствует тому результату, которого вы ожидаете от поэлементного логического И двух векторов.

Реализация оператора `&` таких ограничений не имеет, более того, для логических значений он работает и в ванильном python

```
(True & False) is False
```

Единственным принципиальным различием между операциями `&` и `and` над логическими значениями, является отсутствие (или наличие) отложенного вычисления правой части выражения

```
>>> False and (0/0 != 0)
False
>>> False & (0/0 != 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Но в данном случае это роли не играет.

Comment: мне кажется этот ответ лучше отвечает на вопрос

Comment: @MaxU Мы просто осветили две разные стороны вопроса, и ответы дополняют друг друга :)